# Import Grails application context of inplace plugin

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, ioc-container, autowired

I have a project setup that consists of a regular Grails application and an inplace Grails plugin. My Grails application uses the inplace plugin. Inside my inplace plugin I autowire a couple of components using Spring annotations in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    xmlns context: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context'
    context.'component-scan'('base-package': 'some.pkg.inplace')
}
```

For my regular Grails application I could not find out how to import the application context of the inplace plugin. Is there a way to do this using Spring's `<import/>` element? Otherwise, I'd have to put the same code into the `resources.groovy` of my Grails app to scan for the beans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import it by using `importBeans`, like:

```
importBeans("classpath:other-context.groovy")
```

at this case it will import an extra context from classpath (probably your context from inplace plugin is somewhere in classpath also).

Path can be `file:other-context.groovy`, `file:other-context.xml` or even `file:path/to/contexts/*.xml`

BTW, i'm not sure about 'inplace plugins', but traditional plugins can extends existing spring context, there is special method `doWithSpring` at plugin definition. So you can add your own bean here.